# Why do icons get pixelated in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a pdf doc through Indesign. When I put an icon in the document, it gets pixelated. This is how I put the icons in indesign:

ctrl + D  and placed the icon.

I've tried this too: view > Display Performance > High Quality Display. 
After doing this icon looks a bit nice in the indesign but looks very bad in pdf.

this is a screens shot:

[image]

Original Image is a png image and it is very fine.

I am new to design so please pardon if I have written anything technically wrong.

Comment: Do you mean that the original icon is a PNG? If so, are you scaling that image? PNGs are not vectors, so they won't scale well, especially if the icon you are importing is very small.

Comment: @KerriShotts I'm doing the same you as u said, not doing a lot of scaling though. But problem is not yet resolved... what should i do for that

Comment: What are the exact pixel dimensions of the PNG icon?

Answer (score 1):

Setting high quality display wont always bring the image up to full quality, though that would be expected with such a small file.  What are your export settings?  Make sure you are not compressing the image at all when you export to a PDF.  When you open the export dialogue, choose the preset, 'Press quality' and see if that doesn't solve your issue.  Otherwise it may be an issue with your PNG file, or you may have different PPI amounts on both files.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and resolved it by changing the view settings. Instructions here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/photos-blurry-in-indesign/td-p/4402516?page=1

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!  That would help the on screen view, however the OP had already stated that they changed that, and it fixed the screen view, but the PDF output was still low-res.